# Could not get data while updating stored procedure in C#.net

Tags: c#-4.0

Initially data is shown in Crystal Report viewer. But when I edit the stored procedure and verified database in Crystal Report no any data were loaded there but added fields are present there.

In stored procedure I declared some integer values with its default value 0 and selected in Select query.

Comment: Please add some code what you have tried so far. Its easier to help you with your Problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for ur reply. I've solved my problem.
Actually I arranged the parameters in stored procedure and in C# code in ordered manner & I get it solved....

Thanks once again